# Azure durable function running multiple times on startup when running locally

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an http triggered azure durable function with an orchestration trigger called "ExecuteWork" and two activities namely "HandleClaimsForms" and "HandleApplicationForms". I will add the definitions for them below. The function is used to process PDFs in a blob storage container. When running locally it will execute "HandleClaimsForms" four or five times on startup without it being called.

Here are the logs that it is producing:

```
Functions:

        Function1: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/Function1

        ExecuteWork: orchestrationTrigger

        HandleApplicationForms: activityTrigger

        HandleClaimsForms: activityTrigger

[2022-06-07T12:39:44.587Z] Executing 'HandleClaimsForms' (Reason='(null)', Id=c45878fe-35c8-4a57-948e-0b43da969427)
[2022-06-07T12:39:44.587Z] Executing 'HandleClaimsForms' (Reason='(null)', Id=0fb9644d-6748-4791-96cf-a92f6c161a97)
[2022-06-07T12:39:44.587Z] Executing 'HandleClaimsForms' (Reason='(null)', Id=9a39a169-a91d-4524-b5e5-63e6226f70ec)
[2022-06-07T12:39:44.587Z] Executing 'HandleClaimsForms' (Reason='(null)', Id=b3697f6b-7c96-4497-826f-3894359ff361)
[2022-06-07T12:39:44.587Z] Executing 'HandleClaimsForms' (Reason='(null)', Id=3ca3bbce-1657-453b-a5b3-e9dbdb940302)
```

Here are the Function definitions:

**Function entrypoint**

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
            ILogger log)
        {
            string instanceID = await starter.StartNewAsync("ExecuteWork");

            return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceID);
        }
```

**Orchestration trigger**

```
[FunctionName("ExecuteWork")]
        public async Task<bool> ProcessForms(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context,
            ILogger log)
        {
            bool success = true;
            try
            {
                await context.CallActivityAsync("HandleClaimsForms", success);
                await context.CallActivityAsync("HandleApplicationForms", success);

                return success;
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                log.LogInformation($"The following error was thrown: {err}");
                success = false;
                return success;
            }
        }
```

**HandleClaimsForm Activity**

```
        public async Task<bool> ProcessClaimsForms(
            [ActivityTrigger]bool success)
        {

                await _docHandler.Handle();

                return success;
        }
```

**HandleApplicationForm activity**

```
[FunctionName("HandleApplicationForms")]
        public async Task<bool> ProcessApplicationForms(
            [ActivityTrigger]bool success)
        {

            await _appHandler.HandleJsonApplicationFormAsync();

            return success;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the workaround you can follow to resolve the above issue,

Based on the [***MICROSOFT DOCUMENT***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-orchestrations?tabs=csharp#reliability) about the reliability is:

> - *Durable Functions uses event sourcing transparently. Behind the scenes, the await (C#) or yield (JavaScript/Python) operator in an
>   orchestrator function yields control of the orchestrator thread back
>   to the Durable Task Framework dispatcher*.
> - *The orchestrator wakes up and re-executes the entire function from scratch to rebuild the local state whenever an orchestration function
>   is given more work to do (for instance, when a response message is
>   received or a durable timer expires). The Durable Task Framework
>   analyses the orchestration's execution history if the code tries to
>   invoke a function or do any other async task during the replay. In the
>   event that it discovers that the activity function has already run and
>   produced a result, it replays that result while the orchestrator code
>   keeps running. Playback continues until the function code terminates
>   or until additional async work has been scheduled.*

Another, approach is to use the [***dependency injection***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#prerequisites) .

For more information please refer the below links:-

- **SIMILAR SO THREAD**| [***HTTP Trigger on demand azure function calling itself multiple times***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59834265/http-trigger-on-demand-azure-function-calling-itself-multiple-times) & [***Azure Durable Function Activity seems to run multiple times and not complete***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60215295/azure-durable-function-activity-seems-to-run-multiple-times-and-not-complete) .